# CSS border effect?

Tags: html, css

A few months ago I came across a website with a banner using CSS border effects. I thought the trick was neat and it has stuck out in my mind since. Basically they filled up the div with border with to make the header/banner inverted on the sides.

like so...

```
_______
\     /
/     \
-------
```

I was able to get the border to work! However, when I add content, the middle stretches. like so...

```
______
\    /
 |  |
/    \
------
```

How can I make the text float over the borders?

here is my current css:

```
#header {
   height: 120px;
   width: 960px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 60px;
   border-bottom-color: #fff;
   border-top-color: #fff;
   border-left-color: #000;
   border-right-color: #000;    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've made this from scratch, you can use `position: absolute;` for your content to place inside the weird shaped element, also make sure you wrap all these elements inside `position: relative;` container..

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XC7Ez/)

```
.wrap {
    position: relative;    
}

#header { 
    border-top: 100px solid blue;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 50px solid transparent; 
    height: 0; 
    width: 300px; 
} 

#header2 { 
    border-bottom: 100px solid blue;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 50px solid transparent; 
    height: 0; 
    width: 300px; 
} 

.wrap p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100px;
}
```

> Note: Am using `position: absolute;` here, so the weird shaped
>   elements have no contact with the `p` whatsoever, so you need to set
>   the dimensions accordingly to fit your content in that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<div id="header"><div class="text">Hello</div></div>
#header {
height: 120px;
width: 960px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 60px;
border-bottom-color: #fff;
border-top-color: #fff;
border-left-color: #000;
border-right-color: #000;   
}

.text {
position: relative;
color: #FFF;
left: -50px;
z-index: 10;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4zGMN/